# How do I show and hide input when anchor tag is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

How do I hide the `label` and show the `input` when `Edit` is clicked and show `label` and hide the `input` when `Cancel` is clicked?

```
<label class="lblProfile">First Name: </label>
<label class="ansProfile">${resident.firstname}</label>
<input id="firstname"name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="${resident.firstname}"/>
<a> Edit </a>
<a> Cancel </a>
```

Can anyone show me how do I code it?

Comment: First of all try to use `<button>` tag instead of the anchor `<a>` instead, when it comes to toggle rather than navigation. Use `click` event on the `<button>` when it clicked, hide label, reveal input and the same with the cancel `<button`>. There is also pure *CSS* way of doing it, using `<input type="checkbox">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick.

```js
function showhide(which){

 var edit = document.getElementById('edit');
 var cancel = document.getElementById('cancel'); 
 var input = document.getElementById('firstname');
 var label = document.getElementsByClassName('ansProfile')[0];
 
 if(which==='edit'){
    if(edit.checked){
       cancel.checked=false;
       label.style.display='none';
       input.style.display='inline'; 
    }else{
       label.style.display='inline';  
    }
  }else{
     if(cancel.checked){
       edit.checked=false;
       label.style.display='inline';
       input.style.display='none'; 
    }else{
       input.style.display='inline';  
    }  
  }
}
```

```html
<label class="lblProfile">First Name: </label>
<label class="ansProfile">${resident.firstname}</label>
<input id="firstname"name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="${resident.firstname}"/>
<input id='edit' type='checkbox'   onClick='showhide("edit")'/> Edit 
<input id='cancel' type='checkbox' onClick='showhide("cancel")'/> Cancel
```